# rails image_path renders absolute path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that `image_path` should generate a relative path; however, for me it's generating an absolute one and breaks my code.

In my `haml` file:

```
= image_path '/mailers/my_image.png'
```

Renders:

```
http://localhost:3000/mailers/my_image.png
```

Comment: Which rails version you are using?

Comment: I use rails ~> 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing it to `'mailers/my_image.png'`? The leading forward slash is generally expected to generate an absolute path.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path